# Behavior of running ldconfig with a directory argument

Tags: linux, compiling, gcc, ld, ldconfig

I have installed some shared libraries to the non-standard directory `/usr/lib64/mylib`. Then I run `sudo ldconfig /usr/lib64/mylib`. I can assert by running `ldconfig -p` that my libraries are indeed cached.
However when I try to compile a certain program that links to a library which links to another library installed in `/usr/lib64/mylib` I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmy.so.3, needed by ./build/libtools.so.3.1.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

along with a number of undefined references.

This does not happen if I add `/usr/lib64/mylib` to either `/etc/ld.so.conf` or to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So what is then the effect of running `sudo ldconfig /usr/lib64/mylib`?

Edit: I found out that the lines referring to my shared objects get removed when I run `ldconfig -p` a second time, so they remain there for a very brief moment for some reason.